# Realm + React Native best practice user setup with sync

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, realm, es6-modules

I am experimenting with integrating my app with Realm.io.. as it seems like a pretty awesome platform to use. I am trying to login + register users correctly through something like:

```
Realm.Sync.User.register('http://realm-ip:9080', this.state.email, this.state.password, (error, user) => {
  if (!error) {
    var realm = new Realm({
      sync: {
        user: user,
        url: 'realm://realm-ip:9080/~/userRealm',
      },
      schema: [PersonSchema, ConversationSchema]
    });
  }
  else {
    console.log(error);
  }
})
```

This seems to work pretty well. I have similar code for loggin a user into realm. Though, when looking at the Realm JS (React Native) examples here: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/examples/ReactExample/components/realm.js they export the realm object with something like:

```
 export default new Realm({schema: [Todo, TodoList]});
```

Now, this seems pretty neat, and makes the use of `realm` flawlessly in the rest of the app. However, it doesn't make use of the sync object with user details in it, as provided when using `Realm.Sync.User.*` Also I can't figure out the best practice way to achieve this modular design, but still have users login/register via the fist example I showed with `Realm.Sync.User.register()`

The example app here https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/examples/ReactExample  doesn't give solid examples of registering users.

My questions are:

- What's the best way to keep things neat and setup users correctly?
- Is there a better way to access an initialised `realm` object that's been setup with `sync: { user: user, url: 'realm url'}`?
- Is there a better example to learn how to do this from?

If my question doesn't make sense, please let me know and I will try to elaborate... as I realise it might not be easy to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it kind of depends on your situation and there are a number of approaches that could work.
I guess you could do something like this:

```
// realm-container.js

import Realm from 'realm';

export default {
  realm: null,
  initialize: (email, password) => {
    Realm.Sync.User.register('http://realm-ip:9080', email, password, (error, user) => {
      if (!error) {
        this.realm = new Realm({
          sync: {
            user: user,
            url: 'realm://realm-ip:9080/~/userRealm',
          },
          schema: [PersonSchema, ConversationSchema]
        });
      }
      else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })
  }
};
```

Then, if you include that as
    import realmContainer from './realm-container';

you can then call `realmContainer.initialize(email, password)` and  refer to the realm like this: `realmContainer.realm`

Comment: Great suggestion. Thanks for the input. 
I am now trying to figure out how to deal with Authentication state. Can't see anything in realm docs about that.

Comment: Something went wrong.
I cannot reasign this.realm. The realmContainer.realm after initialize is null.